# Java "Could not find or load main class" despite specifying class path?

Tags: java

I have a simplified Java project with the following structure:

```
.
└── hello
    ├── HelloWorld.class
    └── HelloWorld.java
```

where `HelloWorld.java` reads

```java
package hello;

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

In the project directory, if I run `java hello.HelloWorld` the program runs:

```
~/D/S/my-java-project> java hello.HelloWorld
Hello World!
```

Reading through https://www.baeldung.com/java-could-not-find-load-main-class, I would expect that if I go to the `hello` directory and run the same command but specify the class path as the parent directory, it would work; however, I get a `Could not find or load main class` error:

```
~/D/S/my-java-project> cd hello
~/D/S/m/hello> java hello.HelloWorld -cp ..
Error: Could not find or load main class hello.HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hello.HelloWorld
```

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: `java hello.HelloWorld -cp ..` is passing the argument to the program, not to the JVM. Use `java -cp .. hello.HelloWorld`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-cp` option must precede the name of the class, otherwise it would be treated as an argument to the program:

```
java -cp .. hello.HelloWorld
```